# Error Msg 823, Level 24, State 2, Line 1

Tags: sql-server

We have been recieving the error below in one of our server during restoring a database. Has anyone experienced the same problem? If yes can you please share how you fixed it?

The operating system returned error 38(Reached the end of the file.) to SQL Server during a read at offset 0x000001f3400000 in file 'H:\Data\XXXX_data.mdf:MSSQL_DBCC17'. Additional messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online

Comment: Have you tried the suggested DBCC CHECKDB?  Also, verify the backup with RESTORE VERIFYONLY - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189587.aspx

Comment: There's a good link on the Microsoft KB site that gives you steps to troubleshoot this error. Good luck! http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015755

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of this occurring during a restore of multiple databases, non-sequentially (i.e.: multiple restores occurring on different SPIDs at once), after a drive failure, on a hyper-V VM.

(I'm sorry to include all of those caveats, but that was the situation... and I'd hate to find out that any one factor changes the results.)

Sequential restores (only one at a time) seemed to have resolved the issue.